# To show, that the inverse function is not differentiable at $\mathbf 0$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inverse

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ by $f(\mathbf x)=\|\mathbf x\|^2 \mathbf x$. To show, that the inverse function is not differentiable at $\mathbf 0$.

I am not able to find the inverse of the function. Since we know that inverse of column vectors does not exists.

Comment: What are you talking about "inverse of column vectors"? $f$ is a function which stretches / shrinks a vector, and $f^{-1}$ shrinks / stretches them back.

Comment: we have to find the inverse of f to check its differentiability at 0

Comment: Yes, that is what the exercise says. By what do you mean by "inverse of column vectors does not exist"? That doesn't really seem to have anything to do with the exercise.

Comment: here x is a column vector

Comment: I suspect that you're confusing "inverse", used in the "inverse-function" sense, with "inverse" used in the sense of a multiplicative matrix inverse (i.e., a matrix $B$ with $BA = AB = I$). For the function $h$ given by $v \mapsto Av$, if there's an inverse matrix $B$, then the function $u \mapsto Bu$ is the inverse function of $h$. But for most functions --- ones that are not linear, for instance --- inverse functions an matrix-inverse are completely unrelated ideas.

Comment: Do not confuse the inverse of a function with inverting numbers! The function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x$ is self inverse, so it is its own inverse! It's inverse is **not**  $x \mapsto x^{-1}$!

Answer (score 4):

Think about what $f(x)$ does: it scales every vector in $n$-space by the square of its length.  In other words, it maps $x$ to a vector in the same direction, but with magnitude $\|x\|^3$ (because $x$ already has magnitude $\|x\|$).  To find the inverse, let's say $u = f(x)$.  Then we know $u$ is in the same direction as $x$, so we need only recover $\|x\|$ from $\|u\|$.  But since $\|u\| = \|x\|^3$, we have $\|x\| = \|u\|^{1/3}$.  So we can recover $x$ from $u$ by

\begin{equation*}
f^{-1}(u) = \|u\|^{1/3} \frac{u}{\|u\|} = \|u\|^{-2/3} u
\end{equation*}

for $u \neq 0$.  We also define $f^{-1}(0) = 0$.

From here you can see that the problem with taking the derivative of $f^{-1}$ is that it will involve $\|u\|^{-4/3}$, which doesn't exist at zero.  I'll let you work the full details of the derivative out for yourself.

Comment: Why $f^{-1}(u) = \|u\|^{1/3} \frac{u}{\|u\|}$? and "the derivative of $f^{−1}$  will involve $‖u‖^{−4/3}$"?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify first: by the inverse function we mean function $g:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ such that $$f\circ g = g\circ f = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^n}$$ which has nothing to do with "inverse of column vectors", whatever you meant by that.

This inverse function $g$ is not hard to find, as already explained by cderwin, but we don't even need to know exact formula to prove the claim. Well, we need some formula, it will be clear what I mean soon.

Here's the deal. From $f(x) = \|x\|^2 x$ we conclude that given any unit vector $e$ (i.e. $\|e\| = 1$), we have $f(te) = t^3e$. It immediately follows that for unit vector $e$ we will have $g(te) = \sqrt[3]{t\,}e$.

Now, if $g$ were differentiable at $0$, then all partial derivatives $\partial_ig_j(0)$ would exist. But,

$$\partial_ig_i(0) = \left.\frac d{dt}g_i(te_i)\right|_0 = \left.\frac d{dt}\sqrt[3]t\,\right|_0$$ doesn't exist. We conclude that $g$ is not differentiable at $0$.